# Creating new rows,while data from 1 column take from other table

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to know all unique id of creatures on specific map and made this query.

```
select DISTINCT id a from creature
    where id in( select entry from creature_template where map=209);
```

It works fine.

Now i want to insert new rows in other table,where first column will be different numbers from first query and other columns are constants.

```
insert into creature_loot_template (entry,ChanceOrQuestChance,groupid,mincountOrRef)
select entry,'0.1','1','-11111' from creature_template
where entry=(select DISTINCT id a from creature where id in( select entry from creature_template where map=209));
```

Result - Subquery returns more than 1 row. Do i need to use some kind of join or union there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix that you have to put IN instead of =

```
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template(entry, 
                                   ChanceOrQuestChance, 
                                   groupid,
                                   mincountOrRef)
SELECT entry, '0.1', '1', '-11111'
FROM creature_template
WHERE entry IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id a
    FROM creature
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT entry
        FROM creature_template
        WHERE map = 209
        )
    );
```

**=** expects a comparison from one to one, **IN** compares one to many.

---

Further reading your query, since you are inserting the same values for every column except entry, i think that you might be able to accomplish what you want easier with:

```
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template(entry, 
                                   ChanceOrQuestChance, 
                                   groupid,
                                   mincountOrRef)
SELECT DISTINCT entry,
  '0.1',
  '1',
  '-11111'
FROM creature_template ct
INNER JOIN creature c ON ct.entry = c.id
WHERE ct.map = 209;
```

Comment: That gives me  Duplicate entry '5648-0' for key 'PRIMARY' That's strange,because in this table a lot of same entry.

Comment: Ok i solved it. Need to use before query: delete from creature_loot_template  where mincountOrRef='-11111'; Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your first query returns more than one row?

In that case, you need to use `IN` rather than `=` to attach it as the source of your `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template
  (entry,ChanceOrQuestChance,groupid,mincountOrRef)
  (
  SELECT
    entry,'0.1','1','-11111'
  FROM
    creature_template
  WHERE
    entry IN         -- Use IN rather than = here. --
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT id a
      FROM creature
      WHERE id IN
      (
        SELECT entry
        FROM creature_template
        WHERE map=209
      )
    )
  )
;
```